# Swing / Java2D statistics and visualisation libraries

Tags: java, swing, statistics, java-2d, visualization

I'm looking for a multifaceted Java2D / Swing visualisation library with which I can render different statistics. Specifically, I'm looking for timeline plotting (with a configurable scrolling and compressing timeline and the ability to chart events at certain points along the timeline), line charts, pie charts, and so on, but if you could list the ones that you currently use or recommend, that would be cool, cheers :) Of importance is high-performanceness, and perhaps the ability to connect to existing datasets or event systems such as Esper.

I will continually update this post with what the community post as answers.

- JFreeChart (http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/).

Addendum: There's a page of [static examples](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) and comprehensive suite of [live demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) available via Java Web Start.